# jruby + no public constructor

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Using JRuby 1.6.0RC1

I've got a java file like

```
package com.foo.bar

public class Foo
{
Foo(String baz){}
}
```

If, in jruby, I do

```
com.foo.bar.Foo.new "foo"
```

then I get

```
TypeError: no public constructors for Java::ComFooBar::Foo
```

Reading http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5009 makes me thing this is WAD, but how do I get around the problem without altering the java file?

Subclassing Foo and then instantiating I get a different error:

> ArgumentError: Constructor
>   invocation failed: tried to access
>   method
>   com.foo.bar.Foo.(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   from class
>   org.jruby.proxy.com.foo.bar.Foo$Proxy0

EDIT:

Got it to work through help from Headius on IRC. The following works, but could possibly be more intelligent:

```
 def package_local_constructor klass,*values
    constructors = klass.java_class.declared_constructors
    constructors.each do |c|
      c.accessible = true
      begin
        return c.new_instance(*values).to_java
      rescue TypeError 
        false
      end
    end
    raise TypeError,"found no matching constructor for " + klass.to_s + "(" + value.class + ")"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can use the reflection API to do something like:

```
Constructor constructor = MyClass.class.getConstructor(Class ... paramTypes);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)constructor.newInstance(Object ... args);
```

Not sure you can do that in JRuby, but I'd imagine you could.

There's an oracle guide to this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: This was far from a complete solution, but it was the closest of the ones I got so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

There indeed is no public constructor for that.  The constructor is package level.

How do other Java classes outside the package `com.foo.bar` acquire objects of this type?  It may be there is already a factory in that package that produces this class by calling the package-scoped constructor, and that you could call from JRuby.

If not, you could make a public factory class in that package, possibly in Java, possibly in Ruby, and call this constructor from there.

You might also be able to monkey-patch to add a ruby-accessible constructor or factory method, without having to modify the Java source.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the constructor is has package level access.

You could try to define your ruby class in the same package as the foo class.

See: [Assigning a Java package to a JRuby class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733125/assigning-a-java-package-to-a-jruby-class)

Comment: I believe this *should* be the right approach, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As a point of reference, I have tried the same thing in groovy, and the only thing I have to do to be able to instantiate the class is to import the package. That makes no difference here though.

Answer (score 0):

Guess the only fixes are the one you proposed, or "remove your initializer from the ruby class" (which may be a bug in jruby--shouldn't it call its ancestor no matter what?) or "make the java class initializer protected access" [I'm not sure why jruby disdains package level so much].

http://betterlogic.com/roger/2011/05/javajavamirah-woe/comment-page-1/#comment-5034